Getting HttpErrorResponse in Angular, Http failure during parsing
I am building a RESTful API with a Spring Boot Backend & Angular frontend.
Utilizing a service meant to return a client list as shown below:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientService {
  private baseURL = "http://localhost:9090/clients";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getClientsList(): Observable<Client[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Client[]>(this.baseURL)
  }

As well as the list component:
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let client of clients">
            <td> {{ client.id}}</td>
            <td> {{ client.email}}</td>
            <td> {{ client.firstName }}</td>
            <td> {{ client.lastName}}</td>
            <td> {{ client.phoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

But am receiving a HttpErrorResponse:
{
    "error": {},
    "text": "<table>\n    <c:forEach items=\"${Client}\" var=\"c\" varStatus=\"vStatus\">\n        <tr>\n            <td>${c.id}</td> \n\t\t\t<td>${c.email}</td>\n\t\t\t<td>${c.first_name}</td>\n\t\t\t<td>${c.last_name}</td>\n\t\t\t<td>${c.phone_number}</td>\n            <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"${pStatus}\" name=\"${pStatus}\"></td>\n        </tr>\n    </c:forEach>\n</table>"
}

I've tried multiple other solutions including changing to
getClientsList(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL, {responseType: 'text'})
  }

but still receiving the same error. Is there something I'm missing? The console notifies me of an error with the syntax of the client list component but in my research I'm seeing multiple people say that the error has to do with the parsing of the JSON
My ClientController looks as such on the backend:
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ClientController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepo clientRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/clients")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients() {
        try {
            List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
            clientRepo.findAll().forEach(clientList:: add );
            
            if (clientList.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(clientList ,HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        
    }   


Could you provide the full error messages you're seeing? Also, would it be possible for you to upload either a .HAC with the server response or the snippet of the response?

@Ángel asking people to upload files is not recommended on stack overflow. The goal is to try to get all the information in the question. While what you're suggesting is a good debugging tool generally, it would make it more likely that this question gets closed.

That said, some key useful bits of information is to share what the server sent, so check your network tab and share a sample of the response from the server.

@ShayneMcPherson Issue is in the backend share that code, also try like  this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL)

@NarenMurali I have added the ClientController to the question which includes the method being called to generate a list of clients. I can query this method on DB side however not from client side

What really catches my eye is that the response you're getting is a template-like HTML text. Have you tried consuming your contoller using another tool first? Maybe try and use Postman and see what the server responds. It definitely looks to me like that text you're receiving is something HTTPClient in Angular won't be able to understand.  Another good piece of information you could try to attach here is the Spring config. What's the type of ClientRepo`? How's it configured?

Shouldn't the URL be baseurl/clients, that might be the problem.
getClientsList(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseURL}/clients`);
}

